# Ошибка вы вода данных в NSLog

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

```
NSString *firstNameLastName =@"DavidMatvienko";
NSArray *listItems = [firstNameLastName componentsSeparatedByString:@"David , Matvienko"];
NSLog(@"listItems %@", listItems);
```

Нужно сделать вывод в NSLog типа: David Matvienko; David; Matvienko. 
Почему не хочет работать? Есть варианты?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы неправильно используете `componentsSeparatedByString `. В [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) есть примеры, как его использовать.

Comment: @Anastasia я кажется это понял. Но я не могу найти верный метод..

Comment: @Anastasia нужно сделать разделение по большой букве.. как- то так. Но я не знаю как это найти в документации(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот код ищет первую заглавную букву с конца строки и разделяет по ней, вставляя "; ".

```
NSString* stringToTest = @"DavidMatvienko"; 
NSMutableString* resultString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:stringToTest]; 
NSCharacterSet *upperCaseSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]; 
NSRange upperCaseRange = [stringToTest rangeOfCharacterFromSet: upperCaseSet options:NSBackwardsSearch]; 
if (upperCaseRange.location != NSNotFound) 
{ 
    [resultString insertString:@"; " atIndex:upperCaseRange.location]; 
} 
NSLog(@"%@", resultString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо сначала разделить слово каким-нибудь символом. Для этого необходимо найти заглавную букву и поставить перед ней символ. После чего получившуюся строчку разделить и добавить в массив с помощью componentsSeparatedByString.

```
NSString *firstNameLastName = @"DavidMatvienko";
NSMutableString* mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:firstNameLastName];
NSRange range = [firstNameLastName rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    [mutableString insertString:@"|" atIndex:range.location];

NSArray *listItems = [mutableString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
NSLog(@"listItems %@", listItems);
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть спасибо сказали автору кода.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!)